# UserControl in Gridview (MOdern UI)

Tags: c#, gridview

I have the Gridview:

```
      <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                       <Grid Height="410" Width="410" Background="Transparent">
                         <StackPanel>
                           <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                           <UserControl Content="{Binding Control}"/>
                         </StackPanel>
                      </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridView.ItemTemplate>
            </GridView>
```

And the code that pick up data:

```
public class Trend
{
    public string Query { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public UIElement Control = new MyUserControl1();
}
```

Textblock displays some text but usercontrol doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you registered the user control on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bindings ignore fields. `Control` must be a property.

```
private UIElement _control = new MyUserControl1();
public UIElement Control { get { return _control; } }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading the user control then change  EditFormType to template

```
 EditFormType="Template"
```

And  `<GridView.ItemTemplate>` should be replace  by `<FormTemplate>`.

Try this and leme know